# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer SSL/HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't switch on SSL for my load balancer in AWS Elastic beanstalk.

I add these to my configuration as well as the certificate in the drop down below them.
[image: aws image 1]
When I hit add, I get this warning. The warning seems okay as it is ignoring a deprecated value. The environment goes through it's update, but when complete the fields above are set back to off.

[image: aws image 2]

What's wrong here? Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there an issue with aws elastic beanstalk interface?

[image: lb listener]

Comment: Can you paste your Load Balancer listener

Comment: added, it's tcp and works

Comment: what is the output when you run ```curl -vv https://the-balancer/```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the AWS Elastic beanstalk UI now works to set SSL as the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the AWS EC2 Classic Load Balancer say that the protocol is HTTPS, not SSL: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

Yes, I know that HTTPS is HTTP over SSL, but perhaps AWS GUI does not understand that.

Note that the link also tells how to configure the Class Load Balancer view the AWS CLI, which would give you another way to approach the Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer and see if you get different results.  There are also more detailed error messages out of the CLI, at least on average there are.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, I solved 
just make some changing

```
 Load Balancer Protocol : SSL
 Load Balancer Port : 443
```

And important is :

```
**Instance Protocol : TCP**
Instance Port : "port number"
```

And Cipher
select the Predefined Security Policy
and set the ssl

[image]